# Paying with XLM for Stellar tech help

Tags: assets

I'm having extreme trouble setting up a verified asset.
I don't know how to use Apache to talk to servers to set up CORS.
I don't know how to create a subdomain for well-known stellar.toml
I'm stuck and don't know which direction to go.

Is there somewhere I can find people to help me in exchange for XLM payment?

Comment: I am unaware of an XLM jobs marketplace. Perhaps try on #Jobs channel in https://slack.stellar.org/

Comment: There is a job board now on https://www.lumenauts.com/jobs

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you some direction with the technical issues.

- [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) is a Webserver like [Nginx](https://nginx.org/) or many others. You can use any you are familiar with. Apache won't talk to any other server. It serves the content for you. In this case the `stellar.toml` file. See https://enable-cors.org/server.html for some config examples for [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).
- `.well-known/` is not a subdomain but the path where you make the `stellar.toml` file available. In case you are wondering why that path, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785

Answer (score 1):

For Stellar, the web server Apache is like FileExplorer on Windows for you to hold/host files. These files are most likely the history archive files, which are generated at checkpoints at at regular intervals.

> how Apache looks like -> have a look at http://torrent.ubuntu.com

---

CORS is the privacy policy that allows/blocks visitors coming into your Apache to get the files. The policy is set by you.

[Suppose you set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` for Apache](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html), you are allowing everyone on the web to access, which means no one is blocked.

---

No idea why you would like to demand a subdomain. More explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Read this information related to enabling CORS
https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html

Also you can get good response regarding this on stellar Slack
https://slack.stellar.org/